# parsing and format different rss pubdate

Tags: objective-c, ipad, rss, nsdateformatter

I'm creating a universal feed reader and i need to format the rss pubDate but the rss pubdate is always different, for example:

```
    Wed, 25 May 2011 02:10:00 CEST
    Wed, 25 May 2011 18:54:26 +00:00
    Wed, 25 May 2011 08:13:22 +0000
    Wed, 25 May 2011 14:21:54 GMT
    26 May 2011 10:32:00 +0100
```

I tried to use this code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Wed, 25 May 2011 18:54:26 +00:00"; 
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +00:00"];

NSLocale *enLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]   autorelease];
[df setLocale:enLocale];

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];  
NSLog(@"'%@' = %@", dateString, date);

NSDateFormatter* df2 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df2 setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString2 = [df2 stringFromDate:date];
```

This code, however, works only with one type of rss pubDate, how can fix this problem?? how can create a universal dateformatter??

Answer (score 0):

`pubDate` is in a date format, so you do the same format in your code to reflect that of the pubDate format.

`EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +00:00` is equal to **puDate:** `Wed, 25 May 2011 18:54:26 +00:00`

You just have to compensate for the date format stored in **pubDate**.

Comment: Ok i understand this, but, if in my code i define as date format this:
              EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +00:00
and then i add to my feed reader a feed with different pubDate such as
              26 May 2011 10:32:00 +0100
i obtain a "nil" because the date format are different